# How to hide or show menu labels in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have Electron app and I am trying to hide or show label base on user input. The label aways show.  I am trying to hide or show Tutorials

[image]

```
{
      id: "tut",
      label: "Tutorials",
      submenu: [
        {
          id: "subTut",
          label: "Tutorials",
          click: async () => {
            const { shell } = require("electron");
            await shell.openExternal("https://example.app/tutorials");
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

In my main.js process I call the menu

When I call:

```
Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById("tut").visible = false;
```

it does not hide anything, however it I call

```
Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById("subTut").visible = false;
```

it will hide the sub menu item

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for any that runs across this issue this can be done by using the function

`Menu.setApplicationMenu()`

Just pass object to the function where you call you menu to handle if item is visible or not

```
const MenuItems = (options) => {
  // MENU
  const template = [
{
      label: "Window",
      submenu: [
        {
          visible: options.option, 
          label: "Support",
          click: async () => {
            await shell.openExternal("https://example.com");
          },
        },
       ]
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
};
```

When you run the function for you menu just pass object in function for what's to show.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS, you cannot hide top-level menu items, just submenu items:

> Nota Bene: The enabled and visibility properties are not available for top-level menu items in the tray on macOS.

[Source: docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item)